# Set of $x$ such that $h \mapsto hx$ is proper

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $X$ be a locally compact second countable space, and $G$ a locally compact second countable group wich operates continuously on $X$. If $x \in X$, let $\rho_x : g \mapsto gx$. I would like to know if anything can be said about the topology of the set of $x \in X$ such that $\rho_x$ is proper (that is, for any compact subset $K$ of $X$, $\rho_x^{-1}(K)$ is compact). I know (by looking at examples) it may happen that this set (let us call it $D$) is neither open nor closed. For example is $D$ Borel?

Answer (score 0):

Write $G=\bigcup G_n$ with $G_n$ compact and $G_n$ contained in the interior of $G_{n+1}$; so every compact subset of $G$ is contained in $G_n$ for some $n$. Similarly write $X=\bigcup X_n$, where each $X_n$ is open with compact closure contained in $X_{n+1}$.

Let $P$ be the set of $x\in X$ such that $g\mapsto gx$ is proper. Then
$$P=\{x:\forall n \exists m,\forall g\notin G_n,gx\notin X_m\}=\bigcap_n\bigcup_m\{x:\forall g\notin G_n,gx\notin X_m\}.$$

Since $X_m$ is open, $\{x:\forall g\notin G_n,gx\notin X_m\}=\bigcap_{g\notin G_n}\{x:gx\notin X_m\}$ is closed for each $(n,m)$. So $P$ is a countable intersection of countable union of closed subsets, and in particular is Borel.